# multi-embedded favicon not working in Safari

Tags: safari, favicon

I have a multi-embedded favicon.ico file used in my html doc, it works everywhere except Safari. I have tried clearing cache but nothing seems to work.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
```

Test case: http://chovy.dyndns.org/test/favicon.html

Favicon: http://chovy.dyndns.org/test/favicon.ico

Response header: Content-Type:image/x-icon

Does anyone know why this won't show a favicon for Safari?

Answer (score 0):

Works for me

[image]

Screenshot is taken with Safari 6.0.2.

In case it is just cache problem, you might ignore that problem. Everybody else accessing the page for the first time with Safari will see the icon as there is no cache problem for the first timers.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding type="image/x-icon" to the link tag. Also, safari will note clear cached favicons when clearing browser cache. You need to close Safari and manually remove the file WebpageIcons.db in ~/Library/Safari.